# Angular pipe character in typescript variable definition used as boolean operation OR

Tags: angular, typescript

I working on a Angular code/project, where there is a variable definition like

```
@Input() public someVariable: boolean | false;
```

I am not sure, what is the significance of "|" character in the above line code? I have tried looking this up in Google/SO but couldn't find any resource talking about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: It seems redundant.  `false` is a boolean so why not just have `someVar: boolean`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Thanks for info! I'll delete my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very odd code. It means that `someVariable` can be a `boolean` or the literal type `false`. But of course, `false` **is** a boolean, so it's equivalent to just

```
@Input() public someVariable: boolean;
```

More here: [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

A more typical example would be:

```
public foo: string | number;
```

...which would mean that `foo` could contain a string or a number but not (for instance) an object reference or boolean.

Answer (score 0):

@Input() public someVariable: boolean | false;

This means that someVariable can be assigned either boolean OR false, and no other type. Any type other than those will give complaints from ts compiler

the '|' (pipe operator) is semantically an 'OR' in this case

Comment: The question is `boolean | false`, not `boolean | string`.